# Sending email, id is not passed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I have a page at

http://localhost:3000/email/correspond?id=6

It is a form to send an email. When sent it changes to:

http://localhost:3000/email/correspond

And throws up the error; `Couldn't find User with 'id'=` Which is caused by

```
def set_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

which is in  email_controller (see below)

I can't understand the problem because the id is given in the sending url.

Can anybody explain?

from email_controller.rb

`

```
def correspond
  @cuser = @current_user
  @recipient  = @user
  @title = "Email" 
  if param_posted?(:message)
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])
    if @message.valid?
      PostMailer.say_hello(@cuser, @recipient, @message).deliver_now
      flash[:notice] = "Email sent."
      redirect_to user_path(@recipient)
    end
  end
end

def set_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end`
```

routes.rb

```
Eskvalleytales::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => 'users#index'

  get 'user/:id' => 'user#show'
  get 'user/search' => 'user#search'
  resource :sessions
  get 'session/destroy' => 'sessions#destroy'
  get 'friendship/accept' => 'friendship#accept'
  get 'friendship/decline' => 'friendship#decline'
  get 'friendship/cancel' => 'friendship#cancel'
  get 'friendship/delete' => 'friendship#delete'
  get  'friendship/create' => 'friendship#create'
  get  'email/correspond' =>  'email#correspond'
  post 'email/correspond' => 'email#correspond'
  resources :comments
  resources :users
  resources :subcomments
  resources :profiles
  resources :emails
  resources :users do   
    resources :comments do
      resources  :subcomments
    end
  end
  resources :comments do  
    resources :subcomments
  end
  resources :users do
    resources :emails
    resources :new_file
  end

  resources :users do
    resources :emails do
    end
  end

  resources :users do  
    resources :fiendships
  end

  resources :users do  
    resources :subcomments
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, You don't need to redirect on same action. If you still need than simple check for id in `set_user method`. Like following

```
def set_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id]) if params[:id]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

From your `routes.rb`, you have:

```
post 'email/correspond' => 'email#correspond'
```

That is what is responsible for the route (url) that you have when you send the form : `http://localhost:3000/email/correspond`

However, you are interested in sending the `id` along with the request as a `params` (`/:id`) and not as a `query` (`?id=:id`), since you are looking for this from inside the email controller.

To achieve this, you have to configure your route to take the given `id` along, as follow:

```
post 'email/correspond/:id' => 'email#correspond'
```

Doing this will ensure the id is sent as params, and then when you call your `set_user`

```
def set_user
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

`User.find(params[:id])` looks inside the request's params, and takes whatever is in the place of `/:id` .

Example:

a post request to `"http://localhost:3000/email/correspond/6"` will give you `params[:id]` => `6`

Comment: Thanks that worked. I had to do get 'email/correspond/:id' => 'email#correspond' as well

Comment: Then why  does  get 'user/id' => 'user#show' not have a semi-colon? That's what confused me.